# How to make Apple style programs in Windows

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface

I have a PHP background.  I would like to learn another language to build programs that can be run on Windows.  I have my eye on C#.

What I really would like to accomplish is to be able to make programs on Windows that have a better UI then the traditional Windows program generally has.  For example, I really like the way Apple/Mac programs look.  Apple has iTunes that runs on Windows and looks nothing like a traditional Windows program so I assume it is possible.

So my question, what languages(s) or technologies would you point me towards to accomplish a Windows program that could have a nice UI like the image below instead of the way most Windows programs look?

[image]

What languages and technologies would you recommend for building an app that looks like this that can run on Windows?

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible. You just have to paint your own borders, title bar, etc. This can be done in C++ with WinAPI or more easily in C# with WinForms, so yeah, you're on the right track.

Comment: Please remember to mark the most appropriate response as your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of 3rd part components you can use to spruce up the look and feel of your application. In no order of importance, a few of the big players are:

- Telerik
- DevExpress
- ComponentOne
- Infragistics
- Many others I can't think of off the top of my head

For which ones people like the best, search SO for opinions. Be forewarned, everyone tends to get a bit religious/devoted to the ones they like.

Comment: Thanks for the list, are these all for the same language or different languages?

Comment: These all tend to be Microsoft-stack focused, but have controls for WinForms, ASP.NET/MVC, WPF, Silverlight, and others. I would visit each website and see the ones you like the best. Be forewarned though, they aren't cheap (although I think Telerik offers a bunch of open source stuff for MVC at least). If you want to do it on the cheap, WPF might be a good way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) - it has a tremendous visual flexibility that should enable you to emulate whatever UI style you want, including "Apple style".

Take a quick look at [WPF Showcase](http://windowsclient.net/community/showcase.aspx) to get a feel for what is possible.

Comment: This is likely the "best" option in terms of having full customization capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch). As an alternative you can focus on [mobile web development](http://mobiforge.com/starting/story/a-beginners-guide-mobile-web-development) if you'd rather stick to what you know.

Comment: I have thought about doing Mobile dev and it is awesome but there are a few programs I would really like to build for my desktop

Comment: If you develop a simple REST app in PHP then you can utilize it in both PHP phone development and C# desktop (Winforms/WPF) development. It doesn't have to be an either or.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just starting out doing Windows app development and you are coming from a web development background with skills in JavaScript and HTML, why not consider taking a look at doing Metro style applications for Windows 8? There are several session videos available from Microsoft's recent build conference over at http://www.buildwindows.com/Session. You can download the developer preview which comes with a copy of preview versions of Visual Studio and Expression Blend (make sure you download the ISO with tools) from the site as well.

There are over 154 code samples in JavaScript at: [code.msdn.microsoft.com](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=ProgrammingLanguage&f%5B0%5D.Value=JavaScript&f%5B0%5D.Text=JavaScript).

Comment: Over at the MSDN forums there is a [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdeveloperpreviewgeneral/thread/f02e4f30-0220-4ac3-b6b4-4d523b43c83b) on how to run the developer preview from VHD.

Comment: This is a cool idea however I do not think I can create an app like the image I have in my question with a Metro App

Comment: The app screenshot you have pictured certainly would not follow metro design guidelines, however I don't see any reason you could not do that kind of layout pictured in your screenshot in HTML which means you can do it in Metro.